# cannot find module 'stream/web' @graphql-codegen/cli@4.0.1

Tags: graphql-codegen

I am falling on this error when trying to user codegen@4.0.1
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When i downgrade to codegen@3.2.2
The error goes away

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this by changing my node version to 16.10.0
`nvm install 16.10.0`